# Homology of mapping spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Given a map $f: X → Y$ of CW complexes, one can consider $Map_f(X, Y)$, the set of maps from $X$ to $Y$ that are homotopic to $f$. Is it possible to recover the singular homology $H_i(Map_f(X, Y))$ from knowledge of the singular chains $C_*(X), C_*(Y)$ and the chain map $C_*(f): C_*(X)→ C_*(Y)$?

The following intuition suggests an affirmative answer. There is a functor from $sSet→ sAb$ taking a simplicial set to the free group on simplices. There is a Quillen equivalence between topological spaces and sSet and a Quillen equivalence between $sAb$ and $Ch_{Z}$, the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-chain complexes, by Dold-Kan. Under these equivalences $sSet → sAb$ just takes a topological space to its singular chains. Then $Map_f(X, Y)$ is the internal hom between $X, Y$ in Top
and so its chains $C_*(Map_f(X, Y))$ are the internal hom in $Ch_{Z}$ between $C_*(X), C_*(Y)$, which can be computed from just $C_*(X), C_*(Y)$.

Also, note that $C_*(X × Y)$ can be recovered from $C_*(X), C_*(Y)$, suggesting that $C_*(Map_f(X, Y))$ also be can be recovered from $C_*(X), C_*(Y)$.

Comment: An easier question is to ask if we can compute the rational homology of mapping spaces from the rational chain complexes. The answer to this is no, but with just a few small conditions, if you record the coalgebra structure on homology coming from the diagonal map, then the answer is yes. This follows from the foundational theorems in rational homotopy theory. In particular, there are formulas that for things like the homology of the free loop space that are derived using these techniques.

Comment: The integral question is much trickier and probably deserves to be on math overflow. I think stuff like this has been studied recently.

Comment: Work in the rational case using $L_\infty$-algebras can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4756) (Buijs, Felix, Murillo) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6145) (Berglund), for example.